# How to get any string we want?

Tags: r, regex, string

The string is as shown below:

```
s <- "12N10-3A 12N10-3A-1 12N10-3A-2 YB10L-A2"
```

I can get the strings except from second one.

```
gsub("\\s.*","",s) #12N10-3A
gsub(".*\\s","",s) #YB10L-A2
gsub(".*\\s.*\\s(.*).*\\s(.*)","\\1",s) #12N10-3A-2
```

How to get the second string from s and what's short approach for each code line? I tried what I learnt on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: you want to capture all space separated strings ?

Comment: Thank you. I voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_extract_last` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(s,  regex = '\\S+')
#[1] "YB10L-A2"
```

---

Or use `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(s, 4)
#[1] "YB10L-A2"
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strsplit`:

```
items <- strsplit(s, "\\s+")[[1]]
```

If you want to access the last item, then just use:

```
items[4]

[1] "YB10L-A2"
```

If you really wanted to isolate the last term using `sub`, then here is one way:

```
sub(".*\\s+", "", s)
```

Comment: I couldn't think of that easy way :( So, if I want to get second one I should add [2]. strsplit(s, "\\s+")[[1]][2]. Thank you!